# Probability in an infinite but countable sample space

Tags: probability

Lately I have been trying to understand some things about probability in infinite spaces and I came up with this problem: "Suppose we have an urn with infinite and numbered 1,2,3... balls inside. We randomly pull out one. What is the probability the number of the  ball to be 0mod2?"
My intuition says that this should be 1/2, but how can I prove it?

Comment: A uniform distribution on the integers is a tricky thing. Intuitions should not be trusted. For instance, the intuitive notion that there _is_ a uniform distribution on the integers.